# loss.backward doesn't update weights when using ray package

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm using Python 3.8.5 and Ray 1.8.0 to utilize fractional GPU.

Specifically, I want to parallelize my custom loss function in-and-out process.

(there may be 4 workers when num_gpus=0.25...)

The output tensor include grad_fn, but my code doesn't update weights so the loss doesn't decrease.

Below is my code with simplified custom loss function x**2

---

```
import torch

import ray

training_set = torch.FloatTensor([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])

class DNN(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):

        super(DNN,self).__init__()

        self.linear_1=torch.nn.Linear(2,3)

        self.relu=torch.nn.ReLU()

        self.linear_2=torch.nn.Linear(3,3)

        self.relu=torch.nn.ReLU()

        self.linear_3=torch.nn.Linear(3,2)

    def forward(self,input_tensor):

        linear1=self.linear_1(input_tensor)

        relu1=self.relu(linear1)

        linear2=self.linear_2(relu1)

        relu2=self.relu(linear2)    

        linear3=self.linear_3(relu2)

        output=linear3

        return output

def parallelize_loss(x_ray):

    x_len = len(x_ray)

    parallel_out = ray.get([custom_loss.remote(x, idx) for idx, x in enumerate(x_ray)])

    return sum(parallel_out)/x_len

@ray.remote(num_gpus=0.25)

def custom_loss(x, idx):

    print(x,idx)

    return (x[0]**2 + x[1]**2)

model=DNN()

learning_rate=0.1

epochs=3

optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)

model.eval()

for epoch in range(epochs):

    model.train()

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    train_output=model(training_set)

    loss = parallelize_loss(train_output)
    print("loss at",epoch,"=",loss)

    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: please format your post

Comment: to be more precise: `loss.backward()` does not suppose to update the weights at all. The update takes place in `optimizer.step()`.